# I am trying to torchserve and done all the necessary installations but when i run torchserve command it is showing like this

Tags: pytorch, torchserve

(tserve) C:\Users\SAGAR>torchserve --start --model-store deployment/model-store --models autisumcnn=autisum_resnet18.mar -ncs
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Miniconda\conda-bld\torchserve_1686829011916_h_env\python.exe"  "C:\Users\SAGAR\anaconda3\envs\tserve\Scripts\torchserve.exe" --start --model-store deployment/model-store --models autisumcnn=autisum_resnet18.mar -ncs': The system cannot find the file specified.

But this miniconda folder is not at all present in my c drive. I checked my python path in my system variables it was correct. I don't understand why it is trying to acess python from that location